# ng-model not being updated outside of the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-forms

I am binding an `ng-model` to an input, but the value of the variable it's bound to is not being updated outside of the `div` where that directive is declared:

```
<div input-field
     ng-if="startTypes.selected.value == 'LocalDate' || startTypes.selected.value == 'LocalDateTime'">
  <input id="date" type="text" ng-model="date" input-date>
  <label for="date">Date</label>
  Date inner scope: {{date}}
</div>
Date outer scope: {{date}}
```

When selecting a new date, ony the inner `date` is updated. The outer one remains with the old value (which might be either `undefined` or not depending if I declared it in the controller, it doesn't matter).

I am using [angular-materialize](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/), I am not sure if this is the source of the issue but it doesn't make sense because it is a specific framework for angular to work with the CSS framework [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/).

[This](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#input-date) is the component I am using.

Edit:

I have tried declaring `date` in the controller as `$scope.date = new Date()` and indeed the current date is loaded in the date picker. However when a date is selected and the model changes, it's only updated locally (inner scope), while in the outer scope the old value remains.

Comment: Please post your controller as well, or at least the relevant snippet.

Comment: It isn't relevant. I am not touching `$scope.date`. It's not even defined. I have tried defining it though, with a value of `new Date()` and the initial date in the date picked is indeed the specified date, but when updating it only the inner scope is being updated, not the `$scope.date` from the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `ng-if` creates a child scope which is Prototypically inherited from its current scope while inserting inner template to DOM, hence in this case `ng-model` getting created inside `ng-if`'s child scope. So what happening is while creating a `child scope` it carries the `primitive` datatype values & `reference`(object) datatypes values to child scope, thats why you can see the outer scope `date` is getting value inside `ng-if` date field(only first time). But when you update the value in `date` you will not see the value gets updated to outer scope. Because the way `child scope` has create `primitive type` value not carry their references, where as objects are carried with their references. So you can create a object like `$scope.model = {}` & then define a property into it, that will work. Because object are carried with their references to child scope, updating inner object would sync the outer object as well(they both are same). This rule is called as `Dot Rule` by which you can fix your issue.

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.date = new Date();
```

---

More convenient way to avoid such kind of scope hierarchy is using `controllerAs` pattern while using controller on HTML. In this case you shouldn't be using `$scope` instead you will bind all the properties to controller function context (`this`). Thereafter when using controller you can use `alias` of controller to get the values of controller like `ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"`(here `vm` is alias of controller which has all information binding to `this`)

**HTML**

```
<div input-field
     ng-if="vm.startTypes.selected.value == 'LocalDate' || vm.startTypes.selected.value == 'LocalDateTime'">
  <input id="date" type="text" ng-model="vm.date" input-date>
  <label for="date">Date</label>
  Date inner scope: {{vm.date}}
</div>
Date outer scope: {{vm.date}}
```

Comment: Using `ng-show` (which doesn't create its own scope) can solve the issue also, right?

Comment: @developer033 isn't a correct way to solve the issue, I'd say either `Dot Rule`/`controllerAs`

Comment: @developer033 see its not to solve the issue, it should be appropriate way, like you are saying, `$parent.date` can also fix OP issue.. but people know that is bad pattern thats why no one suggesting that as well..

Comment: No, I didn't say to use `$parent.date`, I said to simply change `ng-if` to `ng-show`, is the use of `ng-show` a bad practice?

Comment: @developer033 yes, it just show and hide the DOM, inner DOM still exists(that would be expensive if the inner DOM has multiple directives)

Comment: Thank you great explanation. If I am not using the `ng-controller` directive to bind a controller to the DOM but `ngRoute` instead, how can I use the `controllerAs` pattern?

Comment: you can have `controllerAs` option available there in routing definition, you could do `controller: 'controllerName', controllerAs: 'vm'`, Please to help you, Thanks :)

Comment: Good explanation! @PankajParkar

Answer (score 1):

You should use an object with a property when binding to `ngModel`.

```
$scope.form = {
   date: new Date()
};
```

Comment: I have used plain objects many times and the binding was done perfectly. Anyway, where does `form` come from?

Comment: its what you want to make of it.

Comment: what the heck that actually worked. May you explain why? I have used `ng-model` before without properties and I've had no issues. What's the reason it's "failing" now?

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` like `ngRepeat` directive creates its own `$scope`.

So you could use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` in this specific case.

From [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

**Example:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testa = false;
    $scope.testb = false;
    $scope.testc = false;
    $scope.testd = false;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  Test A: {{testa}}
  <br /> Test B: {{testb}}
  <br /> Test C: {{testc}}
  <br /> Test D: {{testd}}
  <br />

  <div>
    testa (without ng-if):
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testa" />
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!testa">
    testb (with ng-if):
    <!-- if you don't use $parent testb isn't updated -->
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.testb" />
  </div>
  <div ng-show="!testa">
    testc (with ng-show):
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testc" />
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="testa">
    testd (with ng-hide):
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testd" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why would that help? Anyway, I just tried changing as you suggested and there was no effect.

Comment: ngIf creates its own $scope as ngRepeat.

Comment: Ok I understand. However as I said, I changed my `ng-if` to `ng-show` and the issue remained.