# add a class to element in ng-repeat after some event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm making a playlist. I have this ng-repeat where the current song is highlighted

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs_list">
  <div ng-class="{'true':'current-song'}[song == current_song]">
    {{song.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

now in JS I change the value of `current_song`. I want to apply the class `current-song` to the new element which is now playing currently.

Comment: what is in `current_song` ?

Comment: its a scope variable containing the song which is currently playing, it has title of song, url

Comment: this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/d9Ld4ewx/, check your current_song variable as Rishi suggested

Answer (score 1):

On change of song set $scope.current_song to the new song and in the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs_list">
  <div ng-class="{'current-song':song===current_song}">
    {{song.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs_list">
 <div ng-class="{'current-song': song == current_song}">
  {{song.title}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax, Try with this

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs_list">
  <div ng-class="{'current-song':song.title == current_song}">
    {{song.title}}
 </div>
</div>
```

I suggest, use `song.id` instead of to `song.title` and keep id of current_song as song id.

Comment: I just noticed, what I did is also working, but the class is not applied instantly, rather when I click on a input box on the page and then click outside it then the class is applied to the next element. I think it has something to do with digest cycle

Comment: Solved it, it was due to digest cycle not being fired up so nothing got updated until I did some action to fire it

Comment: @SwapneshKhare how could the digest cycle be an mess here? what you are doing to there that you need to run digest cycle..

Answer (score 0):

The way `ng-repeat` works is, it creates a child scope which is prototypically inherited from current scope. Therefore inner `current_song` value would not update per that. I don't want to repeat answer again why it is not working, you can find [**explanation here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403437/2435473). You have to use `Dot Rule` in order to get correct selected `current_song` value inside `ng-repeat`, & while having condition you should compare it with its unique_id (assuming you have `id` prop here).

```
$scope.model = {
    current_song: null
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="song in songs_list">
  <div ng-class="{'current-song': song.id == model.current_song.id}">
    {{song.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey mate, there are some syntax errors.. take a look :D

Comment: Thanks for heads up mate, you could propose edit, I'd love to accept it.

Comment: The fact is that my edit would automatically update your answer without your permission.. that's why I didn't.. but let me correct one thing :D

Comment: If you're pretty confident then That is not a problem, though thanks man..

Comment: Pleasure to help :)

Comment: @Swapnesh Khare does it helped you?