# Working with a form inside an Angular UI Bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a button that pops up an Angular UI Bootstrap popover, using a template.

You can view it in [this pen](https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/pbaoRr)

The popover template is a form with a table containing a series of text fields with ng-models:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="filterPopoverTemplate.html">
<div class="filters">
  <form>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" size="5" ng-model="filterHsCodeRestricted"></td>
          <td>HS Code Restricted</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" size="5" ng-model="filterHsCode10"></td>
          <td>HS Code 10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" size="5" ng-model="filterCOD"></td>
          <td>COD</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="filter-buttons">
      <button tabindex="0" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="applyFilters()">Apply</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="resetFilters()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</script>
```

I have a "reset" button which calls a function that I want to reset all the ng-models to empty strings:

```
   $scope.resetFilters = function () {
    $scope.filterHsCodeRestricted = '';
    $scope.filterHsCode10 = '';
    $scope.filterCOD = '';
  };
```

However, if I type something into the field and click "reset", the model is not being set to the empty string.  I've done this elsewhere and it works, just not inside a popover template, so I assume it has something to do with the fields being in a popover ng-template. How do I "access" those?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but shouldnt the variables be binded to a model to be able to use `ng-model`? Like so `mymodelname.filterHsCodeRestricted`

Comment: I've used it the way i have it else where in the app.  AFAIK you just need to declare a variable on the $scope to use ng-model.  This is Angular 1.4.1.

Comment: *always always always* use an object in `ng-model`. Binding to primitives will break in child scopes

Comment: This 3 minute video is well worth the time to understand issue https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the model without the `DotRule` or `controller-as-syntax`.

The whole problem was already explained by [Pankaj Parkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2435473/pankaj-parkar) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403203/ng-model-not-being-updated-outside-of-the-scope/38403437#38403437).

So, to make it work, you have to create a new object, ex:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Then, build your `ng-model's` like this:

```
ng-model="model.filterCOD"
```

And so on..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is :

You need to define another ng-controller inside your filterPopoverTemplate.html

```
  app.controller('poptemp', function($scope) {

  $scope.resetFilters = function() {  

    $scope.filterHsCodeRestricted = '';
    $scope.filterHsCode10 = '';
    $scope.filterCOD = '';
    $scope.filterPOE = '';
    $scope.filterECCN = '';
    $scope.filterItemCondition = '';

  };

});
```

Check the [corrected code here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgzvyY)